# Where does systemd actually search for units?

Tags: environment-variables, path, systemd, xdg

Today I spent *too many* hours figuring out what is wrong with my systemd which was refusing to find units in `.config/systemd/user`.

The symptoms were:

- `systemd-analyze --user verify <unit>` worked
- I was 100% sure the unit file physically was there
- The whole `$HOME` directory and `.config/systemd` mounted on another distro also worked

I really wish someone posted this earlier so I am here, doing the thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TL;DR

Run `systemctl [--user] show -p UnitPath --value` to see where is systemd looking for units. There are **not** supposed to be any substitutable parts, e.g. `${HOME}`.

(See my example output for a working example)

## Other things you can check if systemd can't find your unit:

- The unit phsysically exists (try to find the unit file)
- Check `systemd-analyze [--user] verify <unit>`
- systemd is reloaded: `systemd [--user] daemon-reload`
- Try to find your unit in `systemctl [--user] --list-units`
- Try checking the whole `systemctl [--user] show` for unexpected output (see my working output)

My working `systemctl show` output:

```
[...]
Environment=HOME=/home/<USERNAME> LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LOGNAME=<USERNAME> MAIL=/var/spool/mail/<USERNAME> PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin SHELL=/bin/bash USER=<USERNAME> XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000 DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus DISPLAY=:0 XAUTHORITY=/home/<USERNAME>/.Xauthority
ConfirmSpawn=no
ShowStatus=no
UnitPath=/home/<USERNAME>/.config/systemd/user.control /run/user/1000/systemd/user.control /run/user/1000/systemd/transient /run/user/1000/systemd/generator.early /etc/xdg/systemd/user /home/<USERNAME>/.config/systemd/user /etc/systemd/user /run/user/1000/systemd/user /run/systemd/user /run/user/1000/systemd/generator
 /home/<USERNAME>/.local/share/systemd/user /usr/local/share/systemd/user /usr/share/systemd/user /usr/local/lib/systemd/user /usr/lib/systemd/user /run/user/1000/systemd/generator.late
[...]
```

*your output can and probably will have slightly different paths*

#### Future me

You need to check `systemctl --user show -p UnitPath --value` for malformed values, in your case it literally reads `/${HOME}/.config/systemd/user.control [...]` as opposed to `/home/<USERNAME>/.config/systemd/user.control [...]`

systemd uses `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` to lookup where the config directory is - [source code](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/src/basic/path-lookup.c). You have `XDG_CONFIG_HOME=${HOME}/.config` in `/etc/environment` file, which apparently doesn't expand and will ruin your `systemd --user` instance